# ICONS are not showing up In the toolbar section TinyMCE Django

Tags: django, tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins, django-tinymce

The icons are not showing up in the toolbar section.
[image]

TinyMCE=3.6.0

settings.py
`TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(STATIC_URL, "tinymce/tinymce.min.js") TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, "tinymce") TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = { "height": "320px", "width": "800px", "selector": "textarea", "plugins": "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor searchreplace visualblocks code " "fullscreen insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount spellchecker", "toolbar": '''undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontselect fontsizeselect formatselect | alignleft  aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist checklist | forecolor  backcolor casechange permanentpen formatpainter removeformat | pagebreak | charmap emoticons |  fullscreen  preview save print | insertfile image media pageembed template link anchor codesample |  a11ycheck ltr rtl | showcomments addcomment code''', "custom_undo_redo_levels": 10, "language": "en",  # To force a specific language instead of the Django current language. }`

I am using TinyMCE in my Django application, but the icons in the toolbar are not showing up. I have checked that the icons are included in the toolbar configuration and that the necessary CSS and JavaScript files are loaded. I have also tried clearing my browser cache and reloading the page, but the issue persists. I expected the icons to appear in the toolbar as in the TinyMCE documentation. What could be causing this issue?